# terraform provider + docker registry v2 = 404

Tags: api, docker, registry, terraform

I am trying to start some containers using terraform, pulling those from my own registry but just can't get past the **pinging docker server** validation, where I get a fugly: `* Error pinging Docker server: API error (404): 404 page not found` error.

For better explaining this, I started the registry as [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) points out; afterwards pushed an image and tried to apply a very basic `.tf` configuration using terraform:

*docker.tf*

```
# set provider to local registry
provider "docker" {
    host = "http://docker.localhost.com:5000/v2/ubuntu"
}

# create container
resource "docker_container" "test" {
    image = "latest"
    name = "test"
}
```

I can pull the manifests and the images using a URL like: `http://docker.localhost.com:5000/v2/ubuntu/_manifests/latest` without much of a problem but when running **terraform** things go south and all I get is an error.

Checking the registry logs I see this when I run terraform:

```
`172.*.*.1 - - [04/Apr/2016:18:30:28 +0000] "GET /v2/ubuntu/_ping HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "" "go-dockerclient"`
```

Tried the same manually using CURL and had a look at the API docs but can't find anywhere `_ping`being implemented so at this point all I'd ask for is a way to bypass this check. **Is there a way to do it?**

I have no authentication set so far, so this (*I believe*) is no authentication BS... yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker host in the docker provider points to the Docker daemon and not a docker registry.

The `go-dockerclient` that terraform uses internally is hitting this endpoint of the Docker remote API - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.20/#ping-the-docker-server

To pull from your registry, you will have to do something like below:

```
resource "docker_container" "test" {
    image = "docker.localhost.com:5000/org/some-image:latest"
    name = "test"
}
```

Comment: Yah, that would make sense in v1.2 not 2.0, this is not likely to fix anything :-( thanks though

Comment: @monchitos82 what do you mean 1.2 vs 2.0??

Comment: I was confusing docs, I was looking at the registry docs while you were pointing to the engine one's... must try those

Comment: @monchitos82 - read the whole answer again. You are trying to talk to a registry, while the terraform provider talks to the docker engine.

Comment: You were right, also must note the provider was not even needed here since I tagged the image to be fetched from the local registry